# Numpy random choice multiple loops

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to perform multiple simulations many times to get a desired simulation distribution. I have a dataset that looks like the one below.

```
fruit_type, reading, prob
Apple, 12,.05
apple, 15, .5
orange 18, .99
```

An example of my code is below.

```
def sim(seconds):
    output = pd.DataFrame()
    current = []
    #output = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(1, 100000000):
        if data2['fruit_type'].all() == 'Apple':
            hostrecord1 = np.random.choice(data2['reading'], size=23, replace=True, p=data2['prob'])
            current = hostrecord1.sum() + 150

        if data2['fruit_type'].all() == 'Orange':
            hostrecord2 = np.random.choice(data2['reading'], size=23, replace=True, p=data2['prob'])
            current = hostrecord2.sum() + 150

        if data2['fruit_type'].all() == 'Peach':
            hostrecord3 = np.random.choice(data2['reading'], size=20, replace=True, p=data2['prob'])
            current = hostrecord3.sum() + 150

    #put all records in one array
    #return all records 
    output = pd.concat(current)
    return output
```

I am trying to figure out how to perform multiple simulations with different conditions varying by `fruit_type`, but currently can't figure out the logic. Each simulation should select specific rows in relation to the `fruit_type` so the simulations are specified by `fruit_type` so part of it.  The size of each sample is different by design as each `fruit_type` has different conditions.

My expected output is an array of all the simulation values. I also want to append all the results into one pandas dataframe.

Comment: Do any of the `if` statements return `True`?

Comment: yes they are selecting the fruit_type right?

Comment: Keep in mind this is sample dataset and does not reflect my actual data

Comment: I'm confused.  First at the behavior of `data2['fruit_type'].all()` -- it appears to always return the `data2['fruit_type'].values[-1]`.  And second, how does that allow you to run different simulations because `data2` doesn't change as `i` increases, so you will always run through the same if statement.

Comment: I agree. That makes sense how can I loop through all the values to get just the simulation number by fruit_type? I cannot figure out the logic. But you understand what I am trying to do correct?

Comment: No I do not.  A.) Each simulation `i` should be different based on what columns/rows of `data2`?  B.)  Each simulation `i` should select records from all of `data2`, or just part of it?  C.)  Why is the size in `choice` different for each `if` statement.  Finally, what is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is an array of all the simulation values. The size is different by design as each fruit_type has different conditions. Each simulation should select specific rows in relation to the fruit_type so the simulations are specified by fruit_type so part of it.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your input data? are you trying to do a bootstrap on `sum` statistics but requires different sample size for each fruit?

Comment: The input data is above. the reading values are discrete so the prob values are an aggregate percentage of the reading values. Each fruit type has a different sample size you are correct so I am trying to do a sample for each fruit type all at once. Each fruit type also has different conditions so I need to change the size of each fruit_type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your explanation is pretty unclear, but here's a guess:

```
# initialize data
In [1]: fruits = ['apple', 'peach', 'orange']
In [2]: data = np.vstack((np.random.choice(fruits, size=10), 
                          np.random.randint(0, 100, size=10), 
                          np.random.rand(10))).T
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['fruit_type', 'reading', 'prob'])
```

The key is indexing `df` such that `df[df.fruit_type == fruit_of_interest]`.  Here is a sample function:

```
def simulate(df, N_trials):
    # replace with actual sizes for ['apple', 'peach', 'orange'] respectively
    sample_sizes = [N1, N2, N3]
    fruits = ['apple', 'peach', 'orange']

    results = np.empty((N_trials, len(fruits))
    for i in xrange(N_trials): # switch to range if using python3
        for j, (fruit, size) in enumerate(zip(fruits, sample_sizes)):
            sim_data = df[df.fruit_type == fruit]
            record = np.random.choice(sim_data.reading, size=size, p=sim_data.prob)
            # do something with the record
            results[i, j] = record.sum()
```

Note that the results array may be too big to fit in memory if you're doing 100 million trials.  It may also be faster if you swap the for loops so the fruit/size one is the outermost for loop.

---

It's also worth noting that instead of `for`-looping, you could always generate a huge sample with `np.random.choice` and then reshape:

```
np.random.choice([0, 1], size=1000000).reshape(10000, 100)
```

would give you 10000 trials with 100 samples each.  This could be useful if your 100 million trials is taking too long -- you could split that into 100 loops with `choice` doing 1 million samples at once.  An example could be

```
def simulate(df, N_trials, chunk_size=10000):
    # replace with actual sizes for ['apple', 'peach', 'orange'] respectively
    sample_sizes = [N1, N2, N3]
    fruits = ['apple', 'peach', 'orange']

    for i in xrange(N_trials/chunk_size): # switch to range if using python3
        chunk_results = np.empty((chunk_size, len(fruits))
        for j, (fruit, size) in enumerate(zip(fruits, sample_sizes)):
            sim_data = df[df.fruit_type == fruit]
            record = np.random.choice(sim_data.reading, size=(chunk_size, size), 
                                      p=sim_data.prob)
            chunk_results[:, j] = record.sum(axis=1)

        # do something intermediate with this chunk
```

Comment: what are you confused about?

Comment: I also have a set dataset that I have to use.

Comment: @user3609179 I know you have a set dataset, but so that I (and you) could test my answer, I provided sample data.  Does this answer help you understand/solve your problem?

Comment: sort of. Can you explain the N1, N2, N3 part? and how I can specify the different sizes for the different fruit_types?

Comment: That's exactly how you specify the different sizes.  Replace N1, N2, N3 for the sizes you want for apple, peach, orange.

Comment: Ok how could I specify a specific size for each fruit. as my dataset is not sorted

Comment: thats why I was using the if statements

Comment: My code shows you how.  If you have 10 fruits, `fruits = [f0, f1, f2, f3, ..., f9]`, then set `sample_sizes = [N0, N1, N2, N3, ..., N9]` where N0 is the sample size for fruit f0, N1 is the sample size for fruit f1, and so on.

Comment: Ok I think I almost have it. Can you show me how to properly append this?Thank you so much for your help

Comment: so I can return the array with the simulated values from all the fruit_types. Also do I need to pass the df through the function?

Comment: Check out the edit.  Yes, you do need to pass the df through.

Comment: also why are you suming? I would like the function to return an array.

Comment: Because you sum in your OP.

Comment: I am getting a 'a must be non-empty' error do you have any ideas?

Comment: at the np.random.choice row

Comment: You probably want to add a check: `if sim_data.size ==0: continue`.